# Problem with viewing DXF files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, dxf

The problem of getting from DXF format, to display in QGIS correctly.  We have loaded it in and fixed the rotation and TTF font mapping problems. That is all great, however the objects are coming in offset to where they should be and I cannot understand why... Maybe something to do with the dxf-shape transformation rather than symbols?

When converted to shapefile in QGIS, and with rotation and TTF font mappings applied, they look like this in QGIS:

[image]

When compared to how they should look, there are some clear issues with placement:

[image]

Please help me to resolve these issues:

1. Point symbols are all offset – if you look at the point featues, you can see in QGIS that none of them are sitting on the Conduit line. Line geometries such as VM Conduit is in the correct place.
2. Point symbol offset for Manholes, Cabinets, SweptTs
3. SweptT rotations are not right... Again compare the two sets of data and you can see it is not correct, please investigate SweptT rotations
4. Colours – I would like to show the same colours as in the DXF – that means built objects are black, planned objects are red. The problem is that once converted to shapefile I cannot find a field to use to apply a different style/colour. Please investigate what you can get out of the DXF.

Essentially, we need to be able to load DXF files into QGIS and have the reference data display the same as it does in the DXF

Please guide

Comment: Alexandr Borzykh is working on a GSoC project for improving GDAL DWG and probably DXF driver by the same http://gsoc2016gdaldwg.blogspot.ru/2016/05/week-1-report.html. He might be interested in getting some test data from you.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.